# Is there a way to route traffic from internet to Cloud Run URL using Google Cloud Load Balancer?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, routes, google-cloud-run, google-cloud-load-balancer

I want to expose some Cloud Runs and other URL endpoints in a single DNS and I am trying to use Load Balancer for that, but i got stuck trying to create a route for a Internet NEG.

I have created the internet backend with the fully qualified domain of my cloud run instance (the same I use to invoke) and then attached to the front end using this rules:

[image]

And then after the setup I ended up with: `The requested URL / was not found on this server. That’s all we know.` when requesting the front end address.

Comment: Are the cloud run services in the same project or in another project?

Comment: another project but the URL address is public

Comment: I wrote something about that: Does it help? https://medium.com/google-cloud/cloud-run-and-load-balancing-go-beyond-your-own-project-adfa1c8b001d

Comment: I followed the tutorial and works fine! thank you! Next I will try using cloud functions as backend service

Answer (score 0):

I am posting Mr @GuillaumeBlaquiere [article](https://medium.com/google-cloud/cloud-run-and-load-balancing-go-beyond-your-own-project-adfa1c8b001d) as answer for the awareness of other users who will search this concern.

The article’s name is “Cloud Run and Load balancing: go beyond your own project!” wherein routing traffic to Cloud Run URL using Google Cloud Load Balancer works.

Comment: write the solution here mentioning that you copied the article and I will check it